# Proof of a theorem of Jean-Pierre Serre on geodesics of closed Riemannian manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

An oft-cited theorem of Serre states that there are infinitely many geodesics between any two points in a closed Riemannian manifold. Could someone please provide an intuitive sketch of the proof?

Comment: This question is not even a real question. I might as well ask you what my favourite colour is.

Comment: Serre has a lot of well-known theorems.  This is like asking about the well-known song of Michael Jackson.

Comment: Differential geometry as a tag?!?

Comment: Azita, if it (the theorem) is well known then why do you ask?

Comment: @Ryan: J.-P. Serre is much better than Michael Jackson.

Comment: @Ryan, I'd say "Billy Jean".

Comment: Hi azita: I see that you've edited your question. Unfortunately, much more modification is needed to make it an appropriate MathOverflow question. For some recommendations, please look over http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/70/how-to-ask-page

Comment: Azita, I took the liberty to re-edit the question. I hope this is what you mean.

Comment: @alvarezpaiva I am still confused: isn't the circle with usual Riemannian metric a closed manifold?

Comment: @Choi: you can go around the circle as many times as you like.

Comment: There is a paper by Nabutovsky and Rotman, available at http://www.math.toronto.edu/alex/morseoct12.pdf in which they give "a somewhat modernized sketch of the proof of Serre’s theorem given by A.Schwarz...."

Comment: The current edit of the question asks a well defined mathematical question, which Barry Cipra gives a good answer to. The original paper of Serre appears to be http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=45386 .

Comment: Cast final vote to re-open, as per David Speyer's comment

Comment: See also: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/57082/is-there-a-unified-reason-that-there-are-an-infinite-number-of-geodesics-between

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The question having been reopened, I'll re-post my comment as an answer:  There is a paper by Nabutovsky and Rotman, available at http://www.math.toronto.edu/alex/morseoct12.pdf in which they give "a somewhat modernized sketch of the proof of Serre’s theorem given by A.Schwarz...."